# Create cURL GET with PHP and HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms, curl

I'd like to send the following cURL statement from my website to my site's API:

```
curl -X GET https://mywebsite.com/api/v1/clients?id_number=<value> -H "Token: TOKEN"
```

Where id_number value comes from a HTML standard form like this:

```
<form action="somethinghere" method="post" target="_blank">
  <input type="text" name="id_number">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Any idea will be appreciated..

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `POST` to submit your HTML form so Get `id_number` from `POST` Params on `PHP` page and add `cURL` code like this:

```
$id_number = $_POST['id_number'];

//Server url
$url = "https://mywebsite.com/api/v1/clients?id_number=".$id_number;

// declare your token here 
// OR define a constant at the top of file like define('TOKEN', 'value of token');
$token = ''; 

$headers = array(
     'Token: '.$token
);

// Send request to Server
$ch = curl_init($url);

// To save response in a variable from server, set headers;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// Get response
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// print response
print_r($response);
```